# creating a multiplication table in python with user input

Tags: python

I am extremely new to python so my question might seem a bit too trivial but believe me, its like rocket science right now for me. So, here it is. I have to create a program that reads single line of user input containing an integer, and print out the multiples of that number up to 12 times that number. For example:

Enter a number: 3

```
3 x 1 = 3
3 x 2 = 6
3 x 3 = 9
3 x 4 = 12
3 x 5 = 15
3 x 6 = 18
3 x 7 = 21
3 x 8 = 24
3 x 9 = 27
3 x 10 = 30
3 x 11 = 33
3 x 12 = 36
```

I think I have to use for and range functions but don't know how to do that. Please help me :(

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Sorry.

Comment: From the number of responses, it appears we will. =/

Comment: Anonymous Python student, you'll quite frequently find people on StackOverflow eager to write trivial code for you, but I promise you this is not in your best interest: you just won't learn as well that way. It's normal to be confused, and asking for help is great. But if you post some code, explain where you've struggled, and ask for guidance, you'll greatly improve your learning experience. Good luck!

Comment: @David: yes, there's always someone who's bored enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really basic program,, all the above things are covered in basic python itself..

You should go through the following links like [Bytes of Python](http://www.swaroopch.org/notes/Python), [LearnPython](http://www.learnpython.org/) etc

There are more tutorials for you to go through and get started..

This line takes the input from the user

```
In [8]: n = raw_input("Enter a number : ")
Enter a number : 5
```

This line iterates over the set of values 1 to 12, in python we can use range function for this..

`range(1, 13)` is there coz it range function stops before the last value..

%s is a string formatting syntax, similar to C, finally `int(n)` is coz inputs are in string format, need to convert it to int before multiplication can happen

```
In [9]: for i in range(1,13):
   ...:     print "%s x %s = %s" %(n, i, i*int(n))
   ...:
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
5 x 11 = 55
5 x 12 = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
for i in range(1,12):
   print int(x)*i
```

But you should check if x is really a number ;)

Comment: If the number entered was `3`, this will print `3`, `33`, `333`, `3333`, etc.

Comment: @jens raw_input returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> inp=int(raw_input('enter an integer'))
enter an integer 5
>>> for i in xrange(1,13):         #use range() if you're on python 3.x
...   print "{0} X {1} = {2}".format(inp,i,inp*i)
... 
5 X 1 = 5
5 X 2 = 10
5 X 3 = 15
5 X 4 = 20
5 X 5 = 25
5 X 6 = 30
5 X 7 = 35
5 X 8 = 40
5 X 9 = 45
5 X 10 = 50
5 X 11 = 55
5 X 12 = 60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var = raw_input("Enter something: ")
print "you entered ", var

for n in range(1, 10):
    prod = int(var)*n
    print str(var) + " X " + str(n) + " = "  + str(prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's an incomprehensible oneliner that will fit in a Tweet, because why not:

```
import itertools;print"\n".join("%d x %d = %d"%(x+(x[0]*x[1],))for x in itertools.product([int(raw_input("Enter a number : "))],range(1,13)))
```